# Undefined control sequence on \idxrefsfont \relax \songlink on titleidx.sbx

Tags: songs

Using lilypond-book to generate the sheet music, but hoping to use the `songs` package for it's Indexing. Running OS X 10.10.5.

I will be using XeLaTeX to render, but at the moment even this MWE won't compile using pdflatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}

\noversenumbers

\newindex{titleidx}{titleidx}

\begin{document}

\showindex[2]{Title Index}{titleidx}

\songsection{Worship Songs}

\begin{songs}{titleidx}
\beginsong{Doxology}[by={Louis Bourgeois and Thomas Ken}]
\beginverse
\[G]Praise God, \[D]from \[Em]Whom \[Bm]all \[Em]bless\[D]ings \[G]flow;
\[G]Praise Him, all \[D]crea\[Em]tures \[C]here \[G]be\[D]low;
\[Em]Praise \[D]Him \[G]a\[D]bove, \[G]ye \[C]heav'n\[D]ly \[Em]host;
\[G]Praise Fa\[Em]ther, \[D]Son, \[Am]and \[G/B G/C]Ho\[D]ly \[G]Ghost.
\[C]A\[G]men.
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

It compiles fine the first time, however after generating the `.sxd` and `.sbx` files:

```
./songidx titleidx.sxd titleidx.sbx
./songidx authidx.sxd authidx.sbx
```

Get the following compilation error.

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (./titleidx.sbx
! Undefined control sequence.
<inserted text> {\idxrefsfont \relax \songlink 
                                                                                             {song1-1.2}{1}}
l.2 \idxentry{Doxology}{\songlink{song1-1.2}{1}}

?
```

Contents of project directory:

```
├── demo.sh
├── mybook.aux
├── mybook.log
├── mybook.pdf
├── mybook.sxc
├── mybook.tex
├── songidx
├── titleidx.sbx
└── titleidx.sxd

0 directories, 9 files
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue... it seems the `\songlink` command is not defined in OS X for some reason. What I just did is to define the command, following the example in the Songs [documentation](http://songs.sourceforge.net/songsdoc/songs.html#sec11.6.3):

I put this in the LaTeX preamble:

```
\newcommand{\songlink}[2]{\hyperlink{#1}{#2}}
```

And it worked!